# convert last character of a string to upper case

Tags: bash

How can I convert last character of the string to upper case ?

ex:

```
foo=test
echo ${foo^}
```

this works for first character

```
Test
```

I want the output to be

```
TesT
```

How does this work?

Comment: There is a very similar question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/168212/change-case-of-n-th-letter-in-a-string) but couldn't find a dupe on SO.

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU sed:

```
foo=test
sed 's/.$/\U&/' <<< "$foo"
```

Using an extra variable:

```
foo=test
tmp="${foo: -1}"
echo "${foo:: -1}${tmp^}"
```